# Jdeveloper 12c unable to run

Tags: java, mysql, weblogic, jdeveloper

i am using jdeveloper 12c with MYSQL database i have created a datasource on weblogic and database connection in jdeveloper now i have 2 problems
1- i cannot run the AppModule ......i see on the internet is to put the mysql connector in weblogic domain ....but i don't know where is this directory can you help me to put it in the right path
2- when i dragged view on jsf page and run it i got errors (mentioned below) but it opens on web but the createinsert button is not working i do not why...how can i save the data in my database which button submit or create or createinsert ?
-the error in (number 2 )

```
[Running application Application5 on IntegratedWebLogicServer...]
[08:39:04 PM] Web Module ViewControllerWebApp.war recognized in project ViewController.jpr
[08:39:05 PM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[08:39:05 PM] Target platform is  (Weblogic 12.x).
[08:39:06 PM] Retrieving existing application information
[08:39:06 PM] Running dependency analysis...
[08:39:06 PM] Deploying 2 profiles...
[08:39:07 PM] Wrote Web Application Module to C:\Users\Keeem\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.0.42.151011.0031\o.j2ee\drs\Application5\ViewControllerWebApp.war
[08:39:07 PM] WARNING: Connection archiveds has no password. archiveds-jdbc.xml file not generated for connection archiveds.
[08:39:07 PM] Wrote Enterprise Application Module to C:\Users\Keeem\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.0.42.151011.0031\o.j2ee\drs\Application5
[08:39:07 PM] Deploying 1 data source(s) to the server...
[08:39:07 PM] Warning: Password for data source archiveds, user root not found. Data source password not deployed to the server.
[08:39:07 PM] Deploying Application...
<oracle.as.ccw.jmx.CCWCache> <CCWCache> <autoRePublish> <CCW auto-republish services error >
com.oracle.cie.servicetable.external.ServiceTableException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc.LocalSvcTblDataSource' didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'jdbc/LocalSvcTblDataSource'
  at com.oracle.cie.servicetable.impl.ServiceTableImpl.getOnlineLocalServiceTableConnection(ServiceTableImpl.java:99)
  at com.oracle.cie.servicetable.impl.ServiceTableImpl.getLocalConnection(ServiceTableImpl.java:223)
  at com.oracle.cie.servicetable.impl.ServiceTableImpl.query(ServiceTableImpl.java:405)
  at com.oracle.cie.servicetable.impl.ServiceTableImpl.query(ServiceTableImpl.java:379)
  at oracle.as.ccw.jmx.CCWCache.autoRePublish(CCWCache.java:320)
  at oracle.as.jmx.framework.wls.spi.WLSInternalEventsListener.processEditSessionChanges(WLSInternalEventsListener.java:376)
  at oracle.as.jmx.framework.wls.spi.WLSInternalEventsListener.handleEvent(WLSInternalEventsListener.java:198)
  at weblogic.management.eventbus.spi.InternalEventBusImpl.send(InternalEventBusImpl.java:75)
  at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessDeploymentReceiverService.doCommit(RuntimeAccessDeploymentReceiverService.java:574)
  at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessDeploymentReceiverService.commit(RuntimeAccessDeploymentReceiverService.java:435)
  at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
  at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.commit(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:64)
  at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.targetserver.AwaitingCommit.callDeploymentReceivers(AwaitingCommit.java:266)
  at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.targetserver.AwaitingCommit.handleCommit(AwaitingCommit.java:121)
  at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.targetserver.AwaitingCommit.receivedCommit(AwaitingCommit.java:44)
  at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.transport.CommonMessageReceiver.receiveRequestCommitMsg(CommonMessageReceiver.java:597)
  at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.transport.CommonMessageReceiver$3.run(CommonMessageReceiver.java:883)
  at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:643)
  at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
  at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
  at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
  at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
  at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc.LocalSvcTblDataSource' didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'jdbc/LocalSvcTblDataSource'
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1224)
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:268)
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:217)
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupIgnorePartition(BasicNamingNode.java:1503)
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.PartitionHandler.lookupSharable(PartitionHandler.java:88)
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookup(ServerNamingNode.java:584)
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.RootNamingNode.lookup(RootNamingNode.java:81)
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:307)
  at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:430)
  at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
  at com.oracle.cie.servicetable.util.JdbcUtil.getOnlineLocalSvcTblConnection(JdbcUtil.java:383)
  at com.oracle.cie.servicetable.impl.ServiceTableImpl.getOnlineLocalServiceTableConnection(ServiceTableImpl.java:92)
  ... 24 more
<oracle.bc4j.mbean.BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack> <BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack> <contextInitialized> <Mbean registered ########....>
<oracle.bc4j.mbean.BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack> <BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack> <contextInitialized> <Mbean registered ########....>
<oracle.bc4j.mbean.BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack> <BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack> <contextInitialized> <Mbean registered ########....>
[08:39:16 PM] Application Deployed Successfully.
[08:39:16 PM] The following URL context root(s) were defined and can be used as a starting point to test your application:
[08:39:16 PM] http://192.168.248.1:7101/Application5-ViewController-context-root
[08:39:16 PM] Elapsed time for deployment:  12 seconds
[08:39:16 PM] ----  Deployment finished.  ----
Run startup time: 11912 ms.
[Application Application5 running on IntegratedWebLogicServer]


Target URL -- http://127.0.0.1:7101/Application5-ViewController-context-root/faces/untitled2.jsf
<org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl> <ViewHandlerImpl> <_isTimestampCheckEnabled> <Apache Trinidad is running with time-stamp checking enabled. This should not be used in a production environment. See the org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CHECK_FILE_MODIFICATION property in WEB-INF/web.xml>
<05/03/2016 8:39:26 PM GMT+03:00> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing the socket, as no data read from it on 127.0.0.1:62,344 during the configured idle timeout of 5 seconds.>
<05/03/2016 8:39:26 PM GMT+03:00> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing the socket, as no data read from it on 127.0.0.1:62,343 during the configured idle timeout of 5 seconds.>
<05/03/2016 8:39:26 PM GMT+03:00> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing the socket, as no data read from it on 127.0.0.1:62,346 during the configured idle timeout of 5 seconds.>
<05/03/2016 8:39:26 PM GMT+03:00> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing the socket, as no data read from it on 127.0.0.1:62,342 during the configured idle timeout of 5 seconds.>
<05/03/2016 8:39:26 PM GMT+03:00> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing the socket, as no data read from it on 127.0.0.1:62,345 during the configured idle timeout of 5 seconds.>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this line-

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc.LocalSvcTblDataSource' didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'jdbc/LocalSvcTblDataSource'
```

It means during the compilation on `weblogic` it did not found the jdbc connection `LocalSvcTblDataSource` you need to check the jndi name is correct or not.

One more thing which I would suggest is: It is better to use a signed software with weblogic (recommended but not compulsory) its Oracle database 11g or 12c.